# Sync application Stream Source in Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring-data, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am designing the Business to Business data stream pipeline with Spring Cloud Dataflow Stream application. HTTP source to Http sync stream pipeline with async. How we can create the design with sync request response channel. I understood in Even driven mechanism its a async calls.

How we can create the design with sync request response channel. I understood in Even driven mechanism its a async calls.